# order a WP query by specific custom field, not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to order some posts by the number of downloads, DESC, and it seems the articles are random displayed:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
‘post_type’ => ‘post’,
‘posts_per_page’ => 12,
‘meta_key’ => ‘post_views_count’,
‘orderby’ => ‘meta_value’,
‘order’ => ‘DESC’
));
```

But strange, the query from Mysql works just fine:

```
`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = ‘post_views_count’ ORDER BY meta_value DESC`
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta_Value field stores values as a string. That's why it returns orderby data in alphabetical order.
f.e.
9,8,7,70,6,5,55,4,3,2,1
To get numerical orderby you should use meta_value_num.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

And also, in your question text, commas are wrong. It should be ', not ‘